# Extract HREF values from HTML string

Tags: c#, webclient

I am attempting to create a crawler that returns only links from a website and i have it to a point that it returns the HTML script.
I am now wanting to use an if statement to check that the string is returned and if it is returned, it searches for all "< a >" tags and shows me the href link.
but I don't know what object to check or what value I should be checking for.

Here is what I have so far:

```
namespace crawler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
            string WebData wc.DownloadString("https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/");
            Console.WriteLine(WebData);
            // if 
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebData))`?

Comment: i have used the null or empty check and it seems to be working well, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at [HTML Agility](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) Pack:

Then you can find all links from a web page like:

```
 var hrefs = new List<string>();
 var hw = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlDocument document = hw.Load(/* your url here */);
 foreach(HtmlNode link in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
 {
    HtmlAttribute attribute = link.Attributes["href"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attribute.Value))
        hrefs.Add(attribute.Value);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I highly recommend using the Agility Pack if anyone is intending on doing any website manipulation/scraping outside of something very basic.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can make a function to return the whole website HTML code as you have done. Here is the one I have!

```
public string GetPageContents()
{
    string link = "https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/"
    string pageContent = "";
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    Stream stream;

    stream = web.OpenRead(link);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        pageContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    stream.Close();

    return pageContents;
}
```

Then you could make a function that would return a substring or a List of substring (meaning that if you wanted all < a > tags you would probably get more than one).

```
List<string> divTags = GetBetweenTags(pageContents, "<div>", "</div>")
```

This would give you a list where you could, for example, make another search for < a > tags inside each of those < div > tags.

```
public List<string> GetBetweenTags(string pageContents, string startTag, string endTag)
{
    Regex rx = new Regex(startTag + "(.*?)" + endTag);
    MatchCollection col = rx.Matches(value);

    List<string> tags = new List<string>();

    foreach(Match s in col)
        tags.Add(s.ToString());

    return tags;
}
```

**Edit:** Wow didn't know of HTML Agility Pack, thanks @Gauravsa i'll update my project to use it!

Comment: Alex, this code was brilliant, as I was looking for a way to do this within an SSIS package's Script Task, without any external dependencies! Thanks!